# Unable to create a constant value of type 'AddressModel'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In the EF query below, any time an child contact address field is assigned to the `Address` property of the `TaxReceiptsWithChargesModel`, I get the error message:

> "Cannot create constant value of type 'AddressModel'"

If I comment out the line that assigns the address, then the error does not occur. What could the issue be?

Edit: Typically, the causes of this problem I've seen elsewhere have to do with using the contains or equals LINQ methods, but the cause of this particular issue seems to lie elsewhere.

Here are the relevant sections of code:

```
            //GetChildContactAddress
            var childContactAddress = lgcCcpModel.ChildContacts
                .Where(cc => cc.UUID == ltrm.ChildContactId)
                .Select(cc => new AddressModel()
                {
                    Address1 = cc.Address.STREET,
                    City = cc.Address.CITY,
                    Province = cc.Address.PROVINCE,
                    PostalCode = cc.Address.POSTALCODE
                }).FirstOrDefault();

        //Create the Tax Receipt Model with the Charge List
        return unitOfWork.LegacyTaxReceiptStore.GetQuery()
            .Where(ltr => ltr.LegacyTaxReceiptId ==         ltrm.LegacyTaxReceiptId)
            .Select(c => new TaxReceiptsWithChargesModel()
            {
                LegacyTaxReceiptId = ltrm.LegacyTaxReceiptId,
                ChildContactId = ltrm.ChildContactId,
                ChildContact = ltrm.ChildContact,
                EmailAddress = ltrm.EmailAddress,
                ChildId = ltrm.ChildId,
                ChildName = ltrm.ChildName,
                ChargesTotal = ltrm.ChargesTotal,
                TaxReceiptAmount = ltrm.TaxReceiptAmount.Value,
                TaxReceiptYear = ltrm.TaxReceiptYear,
                Address = childContactAddress,
                ReceiptNumber = $"{ltrm.TaxReceiptYear}-{ltrm.LegacyTaxReceiptId.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0')}",
                Charges = taxReceiptChargesModelList,
            }).FirstOrDefault();


public class TaxReceiptsWithChargesModel : ITaxReceiptsModel
    {
        public int LegacyTaxReceiptId { get; set; }
        public string ChildContactId { get; set; }
        public string ChildContact { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public IAddressModel Address { get; set; }
        public decimal? OpeningBalance { get; set; }
        public decimal? InvoicesTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal? PaymentsTotal { get; set; }
        public string ChildId { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
        public decimal? ChargesTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal? TaxReceiptAmount { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int TaxReceiptYear { get; set; }
        public string ReceiptNumber { get; set; }
        public int? BinaryDocumentId { get; set; }
        public List<TaxReceiptsChargesModel> Charges { get; set; }
    }

public interface IAddressModel
    {
        string Address1 { get; set; }
        string Address2 { get; set; }
        string City { get; set; }
        string Country { get; set; }
        string PostalCode { get; set; }
        string Province { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `childContactAddress`  object (and also `taxReceiptChargesModelList`) is already in memory and when you try to assign a complex object in the projection of your second query, the Linq provider can't translated that object to SQL. One option can be call `AsEnumerable` extension method:

```
  return unitOfWork.LegacyTaxReceiptStore.GetQuery()
        .Where(ltr => ltr.LegacyTaxReceiptId ==ltrm.LegacyTaxReceiptId)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(c => new TaxReceiptsWithChargesModel()
        {
            LegacyTaxReceiptId = ltrm.LegacyTaxReceiptId,
            ChildContactId = ltrm.ChildContactId,
            ChildContact = ltrm.ChildContact,
            EmailAddress = ltrm.EmailAddress,
            ChildId = ltrm.ChildId,
            ChildName = ltrm.ChildName,
            ChargesTotal = ltrm.ChargesTotal,
            TaxReceiptAmount = ltrm.TaxReceiptAmount.Value,
            TaxReceiptYear = ltrm.TaxReceiptYear,
            Address = childContactAddress,
            ReceiptNumber = $"{ltrm.TaxReceiptYear}-{ltrm.LegacyTaxReceiptId.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0')}",
            Charges = taxReceiptChargesModelList, 
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

### Update

Your issue can be also solve this way:

```
var result=unitOfWork.LegacyTaxReceiptStore.GetQuery()
            .FirstOrDefault(ltr => ltr.LegacyTaxReceiptId ==ltrm.LegacyTaxReceiptId);

return new TaxReceiptsWithChargesModel()
        {
            LegacyTaxReceiptId = result.LegacyTaxReceiptId,
            ChildContactId = result.ChildContactId,
            ChildContact = result.ChildContact,
            EmailAddress = result.EmailAddress,
            ChildId = result.ChildId,
            ChildName = result.ChildName,
            ChargesTotal = result.ChargesTotal,
            TaxReceiptAmount = result.TaxReceiptAmount.Value,
            TaxReceiptYear = result.TaxReceiptYear,
            Address = childContactAddress,
            ReceiptNumber = $"{result.TaxReceiptYear}-{result.LegacyTaxReceiptId.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0')}",
            Charges = taxReceiptChargesModelList,
        };
```

Comment: I tried assigning the address after the initial query, but that produced the same result. I'll take a look at your first suggestion and the other one mentioned above. Thanks!

Comment: That should be due to the string interpolation, I think that is not supported yet in Linq to Entities. I suggest to try with the first solution, `ToString` is also not supported

Comment: Thanks for your help! Solutions 1 and 3 worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply [Serializable()] decorator however you cannot do it to interfaces.

Instead, implement your custom interface with ISerializable {}

A similar question has been answered below, credit of this post goes to Oded.

[Why are interfaces not [Serializable]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639362/why-are-interfaces-not-serializable)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell what is point of using interfaces as a model property.
Microsoft do  not encourage use of in interfaces as a model property. You can restrict changes in your property by using getter and setter methods .
See this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455558/2173098

Comment: Fair enough, good point. This is an inherited code base. Perhaps we can look at making changes to it later on.